# Standard deviation using mrjob in Python is showing the error "file has no attributes to run"

Tags: python, mapreduce, mrjob

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
import statistics
import sys

class MRFindStdev():

    def mapper(self, _, line):
        for number in line.split(','):
            yield number, float(number)

    def reducer(self, _, line):
        numbers = list(self.mapper(line))
        #total_numbers = len(numbers)
        #mean = sum(numbers)/total_numbers
        #print(numbers)
        yield statistics.stdev(numbers)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  MRFindStdev.run()
```

Comment: You need to subclass MRJob: `class MRFindStdev(MRJob):`

Comment: can you please tell me how?

Comment: Put MRJob in () when you define the class as per my previous comment. That tells Python to use the class MRJob as a template when MRFindStdev is created.

Comment: thank you so much for your help

Comment: Can you put the data input and the output as well?

Answer (score 1):

try the following

```
from statistics import stdev
import statistics

class deviation(MRJob):
    def mapper(self, __, line):
        for num in line.split(','):
            yield None, int(num)


    def reducer(self, __, numbr):
        yield "deviation",statistics.stdev(numbr)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    deviation.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll turn my comment into an answer, so it can be accepted.

Subclass `MRJob` when creating `MRFindStdev`:

```
class MRFindStdev(MRJob):
    def mapper(self, _, line):
        # code...
```